# How do I make a christmas tree whose lines go 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 5, 7, 9, 7, 9

Tags: java

How do I make a christmas tree whose lines go 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 5, 7, 9, 7, 9...?

The christmas tree should look like this:

```
               x
              xxx
             xxxxx
              xxx
             xxxxx
            xxxxxxx
             xxxxx
            xxxxxxx
           xxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxx
           xxxxxxxxx
          xxxxxxxxxxx
```

It ask for the user to input the number of rows. I have got this so far. Made a pyrmamid earlier*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pyramide {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // les inn antall rader
        System.out.println("Hvor mange rader skal pyramiden ha?");

        int antallRader;
        Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);
        antallRader = tastatur.nextInt();

        // skrive ut en kolonne som har saa mange rader som det ble angitt
        // for hver verdi som rad kan faa naar rad starter paa 1, er mindre
        // eller lik antallRader, og oekes hver gang med 1)

        // for hver verdi mellom startverdien og sluttverdien med avstand 1
        // gjenta
        for (int rad = 1; rad <= antallRader; rad++) {
            for (int antallTomt = 1; antallTomt <= antallRader - rad; antallTomt++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int antallX = 1; antallX <= 2 * rad - 1; antallX++) {
                System.out.print("x");
            }
            for (int antallX = 1; antallX <= 2 * rad - 1; antallX++) {
                System.out.print("x");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

I figure its a loop that somehow goes +2, +2, -2. But I cant figure out how to program it.

Comment: what's with your comments?

Comment: You're on the right track. One approach is to use a counter and `%`  modulus on it: e.g. `count % 3`. Add +2 to the `width` when result is 0 or 1 and -2 from the `width` when result is 3.

Comment: @rui Poster probably more comfortable with a language that isn't English?

Comment: (Whoops, "..when result is 2.")

Answer (score 4):

You were extremely close.  Please consider:

```
int linjer = 0;
int radDenneGang = 1;
while (linjer < antallRader) {
    int antallRaderDenneGang;
    if (antallRader - linjer >= 3)
        antallRaderDenneGang = radDenneGang + 2;
    else
        antallRaderDenneGang = radDenneGang + antallRader - linjer - 1;
    for (int rad = radDenneGang; rad <= antallRaderDenneGang; rad++) {
        for (int antallTomt = 1; antallTomt <= antallRader - rad; antallTomt++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int antallX = 1; antallX <= 2 * rad - 1; antallX++) {
            System.out.print("x");
        }
        // for (int antallX = 1; antallX <= 2 * rad - 1; antallX++) {
        // System.out.print("x");
        // }
        System.out.println();
    }
    linjer += antallRaderDenneGang - radDenneGang + 1;
    radDenneGang++;
}
```

With `antallRader=15`, it produces the following, beautiful Christmas tree:

```
          x
         xxx
        xxxxx
         xxx
        xxxxx
       xxxxxxx
        xxxxx
       xxxxxxx
      xxxxxxxxx
       xxxxxxx
      xxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxx
      xxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: @user2731202  How were my Danish variable names? ;-)  The wonders of the Internet.

Comment: That plus describing ASCII art as beautiful — even if the code were broken, it'd still be worth an upvote :-)

Comment: @NicholasRiley  But it **is**, is it not?  LOL

Comment: @VeronicaCornejo I can't say I quite approve of the Danish variable names. StackOverflow is English-only, questions / answers are meant to be helpful to future visitors and code with variable names in other languages are more difficult to read. And yes, I know you just added 3 (or so) names to the existing names.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would probably be to abstract stuff. I mean, make a method that prints just one line of this tree:

```
private static void branch(int width,int centerPoint) {
    for (int i = 0; i < centerPoint - width / 2; i++) {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        System.out.print('x');
    }
}
```

Then you can make a tree with any shape you like:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("Hvor mange rader skal pyramiden ha?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numRows = scanner.nextInt();
    int width = 1;
    for (int i = 0;i < numRows;i++) {
        branch(width,numRows / 3 + 2);
        if (width % 3 == 2)
            width -= 2; //Reduces the width by 2 if it's line 2, 5, 8, etc.
        else
            width += 2; //Other lines, increases the width by 2.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go !

```
String x = "                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
int ix = x.indexOf('x');
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    int j = i/3 + i%3;
    System.out.println(x.substring(j, ix + 2*j + 1));
}
```

Output

```
            x
           xxx
          xxxxx
           xxx
          xxxxx
         xxxxxxx
          xxxxx
         xxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxx
         xxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxx
       xxxxxxxxxxx
```